# urxvt not picking up the correct DPI

Tags: rxvt, dpi, high-dpi

I'm running Manjaro Gnome on a HiDPI display. Most things work fine but some programs like `urxvt` or `rofi` don't seem to pick up the correct system-wide DPI settings and look very TINY. I thought I could add something `Xft.dpi` to my `.XResources` but it doesn't have any effect. I know it's picking up the configs in that file because I can change colours etc and they're applied to urxvt but not the DPI for some reason. Should I poke something else as well?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to either:

**a.** Just make the default font size larger:

```
urxvt -fn 'xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:pixelsize=14'
```

**b.** Force your X11 server to return the *right* DPI of your monitor instead of the [made up 96 DPI](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23705).

I did this by putting

```
xrandr --fbmm `xrandr | sed -n '/ connected/s/.* \([0-9]*\)mm x \([0-9]*\)mm/\1x\2/p'`
```

in my `~/.xsession`.